# How to convert List<T> to List<dynamic> WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Lets say I have a Listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

I have a Property:

```
private List<dynamic> _myList;

public List<dynamic> MyList
{
    get { return _myList; }
    set
    {
        if(value==null)return;
        _myList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

okay, now we're getting to my question:
I have Several classes that I will have Lists of and I would like to be able to display them in this ListBox.

**Classes:**

```
public class A
{
    public string S { get; set; }
    public int I { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int C { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string This { get; set; }
    public double That { get; set; }
}
```

**Filling myList**

```
    private void FillA()
    {
        List<A> listA = GetListAFromSomewhere();

        MyList = listA;
    }
    private void FillB()
    {
        List<B> listb = GetListBFromSomewhere();

        MyList = listb;
    }

    private void FillC()
    {
        List<C> listC = GetListCFromSomewhere();

        MyList = listC;
    }
```

I get Exception

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I have tried to cast, and looked for a converter. but cannot seem to figure it out.
It does the same when I change to `List<object>`.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182952/cast-list-of-anonymous-type-to-list-of-dynamic-objects)

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think that your issue caused by covariance/contrvariance. Classes don't support this feature. You can use interface or Cast linq method. See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx 
I mean something like this:

```
MyList = GetListAFromSomewhere().Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
```

Also not sure if your ListBox will work properly with dynamic. You could use inheritance and TemplateSelector in XAML: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418250/WPF-Based-Dynamic-DataTemplateSelector